# What's the difference between "reveal" and "unveil"?

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between "reveal" and "unveil"?Could you please tell me by some samples?Thank you for your kindness:)

Comment: One obvious difference is that apart from contexts such as *Islam forbids women to unveil in public*, that one is almost always used ***metaphorically***. And this specific metaphor simply doesn't work very well in contexts like *The politician made a mistake in unveiling that he was gay*.

Answer (score 3):

**Reveal** means to make known previously unknown information, plans, etc.

For example, *X was forced to reveal the hideout of Y*

**Unveil** means to uncover (something new) as part of a public ceremony.

For example, *X will unveil the plans for his new construction project at the meeting tomorrow.*

In my opinion, the difference is that **reveal** may not always be public, while **unveil** always is.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that **unveiled** requires a *ceremony* - it's common to see uses like "The terrorist plot was unveiled."

Comment: The stress is on the word *public*. Your sentence implies the same thing, that the terrorist plot was made public.